# Multiple fieldset and legend tag selectors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to use fieldset and was expecting a output like following.

[image]

But I just got a horizontal line on top.

Then I looked into the source and found 2 fieldset selectors and same for legend.

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css

```
fieldset {
    min-width: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    border: 0; 
}
fieldset {
    padding: .35em .625em .75em;
    margin: 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

legend {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: inherit;
  color: #333;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

If I comment first fieldset and first legend tag in the inspector. I get the output as expected. Is there another way than commenting these selectors in bootstrap source which I did and it works.

```
<fieldset>
 <legend> Name </legend> 
 <input type="text"> 
</fieldset>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please create a demo of your current output? It is hard to check what you are expecting just with the image.

Comment: Create an extra stylesheer, add the desired styles back and load it after bootstrap. Which is what you should be doing anyway in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you see, seems to be the default Bootstrap styling of a `fieldset` and `legend`.

As can be seen here:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend> Name </legend> 
    <input type="text" /> 
</fieldset>
```

But you can override that. Just make sure that the overwriting rules are after the Bootstrap stylesheet.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
legend {
    border: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend> Name </legend> 
    <input type="text" /> 
</fieldset>
```

It also needs some more tweaking to give the exact result you want...

## Edit

With some tweaking:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 350px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
legend {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  width: auto;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 100;
}
input{ margin: 0; }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>What is your favorite color</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="color" /> Red</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="color" /> Green</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="color" /> Blue</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I make the legend appear on the left.